# If the supplied array of a foreach loop is a function call, is there a performance hit?

Tags: php, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: how is an array in a foreach loop read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685689/php-how-is-an-array-in-a-foreach-loop-read)

If I have a foreach loop that looks like this:

```
//$test->result() returns an array
foreach ($test->result() as $index=>$value) ...
```

Is there an appreciable performance difference as opposed to storing that result in a variable and then using that as the supplied array?

```
$result = $test->result();
foreach ($result as $index=>$value) ...
```

My guess is that there is no performance difference, save perhaps for the slight increase in memory used to store that $result variable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685689/php-how-is-an-array-in-a-foreach-loop-read

Comment: Thank you very much, BoltClock. I only wish I could accept your answer ;-]

Comment: Nah, a comment upvote will do :D